# How to get Firebug to include dynamically loaded pages (jquery.load) in its HTML view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, firebug

I'm working with a page where quite a bit of content is loaded dynamically, with the likes of:

```
     $("#main").load("menu.context.php",{param:active, id: id});
```

This works okay as long as there are no errors in content loaded that way. 
Then I'd like to debug an object loaded that way, and see it in HTML view. I pick the object with the picker, click on it on the crumbpath and...

[image]

...I'm brought to an `<object>` several levels above, where the `.load()` placed all the new content. I can't open it to see the content and traverse its tree.

How can I get Firebug to open that object and show its subtree in the HTML view?

Comment: If there is an error with the load none of the content gets loaded. Look in the Console tab of Firebug for the load requests and you'll see requests and responses along with failures and errors.

Comment: @JayBlanchard: The content is loaded into Firefox, after all the DIV I click on exists in the loaded content. Now if there is an error in the loaded Javascript... Yes, there are errors, visible in Console. If there were none I wouldn't need Firebug in the first place.